# jquery.validate not showing messages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to find out why my jquery.validate script is not showing the messages. Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Trying to display messages in a separate div:

html:

```
  <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
                <label for="vehiclePrice" class="form-control-label vpl">Vehicle Price</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vehiclePrice" placeholder="$0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="25592" required />

                <label for="estimatedTaxesAndFees" class="form-control-label etfl">Estimated Taxes and Fees</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estimatedTaxesAndFees" placeholder="$0" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" value="2843" required />

              </form>

            <div id="error-note"></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#commentForm').validate({
    errorLabelContainer: "#error-note",
    wrapper: "li",
    onfocusout: function(element, event) {
        this.element(element);
    },
    rules: {
        vehiclePrice: 'required',
        estimatedTaxesAndFees: 'required'

    },
    messages: {
        vehiclePrice: 'Please enter vehicle price',
        estimatedTaxesAndFees: 'Please enter taxes and fees
    }
});

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLYf9/3/)

Comment: there is no submit button in the form?

Comment: missing end qoute here `estimatedTaxesAndFees: 'Please enter taxes and fees`?

Comment: There is not submit for this form. It is part of a multipart form that updates content in a div. There is no definitive submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Include jQuery in your fiddle

2) Add submit button to your HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

3) Add missing `'` at the end of your `estimatedTaxesAndFees` message:

```
estimatedTaxesAndFees: 'Please enter taxes and fees' // <-- Here
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLYf9/1/)**

---

You need to add `name` attribute to your `input` to get custom message here:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="vehiclePrice" id="vehiclePrice"
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="estimatedTaxesAndFees"
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLYf9/4/)**

Comment: There is no submit for this form. Part of a larger form experience but the fields just update data. And I could get the "This field is required" generic message (after I added jquery... doh) but it is not showing the unique messaging. I updated my original fiddle.

Comment: That's it. I always forget the name in jquery.validate is muy importante'...  thank you.

Comment: in my case, I added code before validate: e.preventDefault(); So it cannot validate.

Answer (score 2):

you had a unclosed string literal, also in the fiddle jQuery was not included

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#commentForm').validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#error-note",
        wrapper: "li",
        onfocusout: function(element, event) {
            this.element(element);
        },
        rules: {
            vehiclePrice: 'required',
            estimatedTaxesAndFees: 'required'

        },
        messages: {
            vehiclePrice: 'Please enter vehicle price',
            estimatedTaxesAndFees: 'Please enter taxes and fees'//closing ' was missing
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n5pVG/)

The validation will trigger if you clear the contents of a textbox/or you add a submit button to the form/or call the `valid()` method of the form manually

Comment: Sorry should have specified. I can get the "This field is required but it is not showing the unique messages listed in the messages json.